# How do I insert a picture in the comment box for Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to insert a picture in Excel in the worksheet itself, say to pop up when the user hovers over a cell. Many sources online have answered this question by saying you just add a Comment, then click "Format Comment" and set the background fill pattern to be the picture you want.

However, when I click "Format Comment" all I get are font options with no options to specify the background. How can I insert an image on popup in Excel 2013?

Comment: Not programming related - SO is not the place to come if you want to know how to use (MS Office) applications

Comment: I added it here based on this question as precedent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776611/insert-picture-into-excel-cell  I have no problem with moving both of them into superuser however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to right click on the *border* of the comment and select `Format Comment`. If you right click *within the box* of the comment, you will only see font options. See below for the correct placement to see the picture fill options.

Once you open the Format Comment dialog, go to the `Colors and Lines` tab, open the `Color` dropdown and select `Fill Effects`. Then select the `Picture` tab and select the picture you want to use.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: After right click, go to "Format Comment", then "Colors and Lines" tab, then under Fill, click the Color --> Fill Effects --> Picture.  Then just choose the picture, and "Ok" all the way out.  There you go!

Comment: Rats, you're right - I forgot the rest...it's kind of buried in there. Thanks!